# MySQL: json extract remove quotes

Tags: mysql, json

I'm using MySQL 5.7.12 and this is my query.

```
select objectid, (JSON_EXTRACT(fullobject, '$.mail')) as mail from openidm.managedobjects where objecttypes_id=5 and (JSON_EXTRACT(fullobject, '$.mail'))='fake@email.com';
```

And this is the output

```
--------------------------------------------------
| objectid          | mail                       |
--------------------------------------------------
| 001f73d9-f3d      | "fake@email.com"           |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to remove the quotes from the output but since I'm using 5.7.12 I can't do it with `JSON_UNQUOTE()`.

I tryed with `REPLACE()`:

```
select objectid, REPLACE((JSON_EXTRACT(fullobject, '$.mail')), '\"', '') as mail from openidm.managedobjects where objecttypes_id=5 and (JSON_EXTRACT(fullobject, '$.mail'))='fake@email.com';
```

but the output is totally unrelated:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| objectid          | mail                                                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 001f73d9-f3d      | 6C75632E6170617369383840676D61696C2E636F6D           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*EDIT*

This is my `show create table openidm.managedobjects;`

```
CREATE TABLE `managedobjects` (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
`objecttypes_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
`objectid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
`rev` varchar(38) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
`fullobject` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_bin,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    UNIQUE KEY `idx-managedobjects_object` (`objecttypes_id`,`objectid`),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    KEY `fk_managedobjects_objectypes` (`objecttypes_id`),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    CONSTRAINT `fk_managedobjects_objectypes` FOREIGN KEY (`objecttypes_id`) REFERENCES `objecttypes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=445311 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

This is the `fullobject` json:

```
{"telephoneNumber":"077777777","mail":"fake@email.com","msisdnVerified":"true","countryCode":"+44","opCoProfileId":"MSISDN","opCo":"3UK","userName":"077777777","partyID":"777777777","accountStatus":"active","creationDate":"Wed Jan 24 2018 11:33:02 GMT+0100 (CET)","_id":"001f73d9-f3d","_rev":"3","global_id":"001f73d9-f3d","CRSMID":"50000048","migrated":"false","mailVerified":"true","mailVerifiedDate":"Wed Jan 24 2018 11:33:03 GMT+0100 (CET)","dateOfBirth":"1988-02-02","password":{"$crypto":{"type":"x-simple-encryption","value":{"cipher":"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding","salt":"1P3TMv71pASuLkyVLFNnEA==","data":"iyj/h0fMU6aiTTBLL/Bb2w==","iv":"gQ6a5cAJYrtek5vcX8+mfw==","key":"openidm-sym-default","mac":"ntv0yTBDzCb0n8kvW4UklQ=="}}}}
```

Comment: the output `6C75632E6170617369383840676D61696C2E636F6D` is wierd i can not believe `REPLACE` is causing that... Please share the `show create table openidm.managedobjects` and that record of example data..

Comment: Would you please post the result of `SELECT fullobject FROM openidm.managedobjects WHERE objecttypes_id=5`

Comment: I've updated the fullobject json. It's really weird.

Comment: I edited the Fiddle below https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g1tH8dZcmJ6ZAHzH8Bjh7/1 and it is working, but in my table it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the error is related to the connector driver. I'm using mysql-connector-java-5.1.45 with SQL Developer. Still haven't found a resolution (tryed also another version) but doing the replace directly on the mysql server it works.

Comment: This was definitely the issue, running from the server it works good

Answer (score 7):

You can use [trim()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php) function like this:

```
select objectid, 
       TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM 
                 (JSON_EXTRACT(fullobject, '$'))
       ) as mail 
from openidm.managedobjects 
where objecttypes_id=5 
  and (JSON_EXTRACT(fullobject, '$.mail'))='fake@email.com';
```

**EDIT** use `$` not `$.mail`, check this [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g1tH8dZcmJ6ZAHzH8Bjh7/0)

Comment: The output is the same of the replace function

Comment: Wrong edit...With JSON selector `$.mail` you can assume the topicstarter has more JSON elements within the column `fullobject`.. And your data isn't even valid json annymore.

Comment: With $ the value returned is 7B225F6964223A202230303166373364392D663364642D346132322D626363312D613037353538656434656632222C20...

Comment: I edited the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g1tH8dZcmJ6ZAHzH8Bjh7/1 and it is working. But in my environment it's not. I've edited with the full create